# PyAutoGUI ignores colors when locating images

Tags: python, pyautogui

When using `pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen()` to look for images on screen (2x2 black pixels), the function returns coordinates of every single 2x2 matching pixels on screen, completely ignoring their color.

Same thing happens with `locateOnScreen()`, it returns the top-left corner of the region.

Setting grayscale or confidence to various values did not help, any advice?

Comment: No, it's not about color. It just can't match ANY single-colored images. PyAutoGui use PyScreeze to match image, and PyScreeze depends on CV2. Spent 5 hours figuring out what is wrong with CV2, it's just not possible. Image you're looking for must have slightest difference, not monotone.

Comment: Refer this results: [1](https://github.com/jupiterbjy/StackOverFlow/blob/master/_62720079/result.png) [2](https://github.com/jupiterbjy/StackOverFlow/blob/master/_62720079/matched.png). This is visualized result of match, and as you see it just match first pixel regardless of given [target](https://github.com/jupiterbjy/StackOverFlow/blob/master/_62720079/sample.png) image.